# comparing ith index of one list with i+1th index of the other list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe

am trying to compare ith index of one list with i+ index of the second list.

```
val = [10,20,30,40]
val2 = [15,25,45]
```

I wanted to see if `val2[0]<val[1]` using a for loop. How can I do this ?

create a new list when `val2[i] > val[i+1]`

result :

```
val_final = [10,20]
val2_final = [15,25]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip` to iterate over both lists simultaneously

```
[v2<v1 for v1,v2 in zip(val,val2[1:])]
```

If you want to split the compared values into separate lists based on a condition, you could use `zip` again:

```
val_final, val2_final=zip(*[(v1,v2) for v1,v2 in zip(val,val2[1:]) if v2>v1])
```

They're tuples, but you could convert them to lists with `list()`

Also, `val2_final` would be (25,45), not (15,25)

If you wanted to get (15,25), then you'd be getting the `ith` element of the second list as well, which you can also do:

```
val_final, val2_final=zip(*[(v1,v2_minus1) for v1,v2,v2_minus1 in zip(val,val2[1:],val2) if v2>v1])
```

Comment: I was looking for this : [v2<v1 for v1,v2 in zip(val[1:],val2)]

Comment: but, i want 15,25 as the output.

Comment: @pylearner So do `[v2 for v1,v2 in zip(val[1:],val2) if v2 < v1]`

Comment: @pylearner I covered the case for (15,25) output at the end of my post, here it is again: `val_final, val2_final=zip(*[(v1,v2_minus1) for v1,v2,v2_minus1 in zip(val,val2[1:],val2) if v2>v1])`

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
for a,b in zip(val2, val[1:]) :
    if a < b :
        # do something
```

Comment: can you see my edit ? am looking for something like that

Answer (score 0):

This will generate each pair twice as each for loop will go through every item of the list.

You could use some itertools magic here to generate all possible combinations:

```
import itertools
for a, b in itertools.combinations(mylist, 2):
    compare(a, b)
```

---

You could still write this using index-based item access, equivalent to what you are used to, using nested for loops:

```
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(mylist)):
        compare(mylist[i], mylist[j])
```

Of course, this may not look as nice and pythonic but sometimes this is still the easiest and most comprehensible solution, so you should not shy away from solving problems like that.

In your case:

```
val = [10,20,30,40]
val2 = [15,25,45]

    for i in range(len(val)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(val2)):
       #Your logic comes here
```

Comment: can you please see my edited question, am looking for something like that